# How to set a collection as parameter while testing a form with MockMVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockmvc

I want to create some tests for my Controller in Spring Boot. To be concrete I want to create a test for the processing of the form to add a new item. The item belongs to the class Drug and has a collection as a

paramater:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "drug_pet_types", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "drug_id"), inverseJoinColumns = 
@JoinColumn(name = "pet_type_id"))
private Set<PetType> petTypes;`
```

I also have a Validator for this form, which does not allow any empty/null fields.
My question is how to assign a collection as a parameter for mockMvc.perform() method. What do i put instead of the ???????.
Here is the Test:

````
    @Test
    void testProcessCreationFormSuccess() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/drugs/new")
            .param("name", "Test_Drug")
            .param("batchNumber", "255888")
            .param("expirationDate", "2023-05-10")
            .param("petTypes", "_____?????????____")
        )
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
    }```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MockMvc - request parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044021/spring-mockmvc-request-parameter-list)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a POST body, then you can create a `Set` of `PetType` objects and then convert it into `JSON` string using `ObjectMapper`

```
String jsonString = objectMapper().writeValueAsString(Set<PetType>);
```

Then use [content](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#content-java.lang.String-) method to pass json string

```
@Test
void testProcessCreationFormSuccess() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/drugs/new")
        .param("name", "Test_Drug")
        .param("batchNumber", "255888")
        .param("expirationDate", "2023-05-10")
        .param("petTypes", "_____?????????____")
    ).content(jsonString)
        .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.param` method can accept multiple values

```
public MockHttpServletRequestBuilder param(String name, String... values) {
```

You can pass multiple values like this

```
.param("petTypes", "type1", "type2");
```

or you can pass an array

```
String[] typeArray = {"type1", "type2"};
...
.param("petTypes", typeArray);
```